# Define JNDI for EntityManager Wildfly 26.0.0.Final

Tags: wildfly, jndi, jboss5.x, hibernate-entitymanager

Define JNDI for EntityManager Wildfly 26.0.0.Final

I tried to update a web app from jboss 5.1.0.GA to Wildfly 26.0.0.Final.

I use:

- jboss-seam 2.2.1.CR2
- jdk 8u202

The last error was:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."example.ear"."example.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."example.ear"."example.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: controlEnvioSumas


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityManagerFactory not found in JNDI : java:/exampleEntityManagerFactory at org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedPersistenceContext.getEntityManagerFactoryFromJndiOrValueBinding(ManagedPersistenceContext.java:261)

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: exampleEntityManagerFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.exampleEntityManagerFactory
```

Update a web app from jboss 5.1.0.GA to Wildfly 26.Final And updated jars and persistence.xml and components.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Here is my files configurations:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
             
   <persistence-unit name="example">
    
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/exampleDatasource</jta-data-source>
      
      <properties>     
      
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>   
         
         <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/>               
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>       
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="false"/>
                                 
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
         <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/exampleEntityManager"/>
         <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/exampleEntityManagerFactory"/>         
         
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="2000"/>
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="1000"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="1000"/>
     <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**components.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components >

   <core:init debug="@debug@" jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@"/>

   <core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="500"
                 conversation-timeout="12000000"
                 conversation-id-parameter="cid"
                 parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid"/>

   <web:hot-deploy-filter url-pattern="*.seam"/>
   
    
    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager" auto-create="true" persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/exampleEntityManagerFactory"/>

   <drools:rule-base name="securityRules">
      <drools:rule-files>
         <value>/security.drl</value>
      </drools:rule-files>
   </drools:rule-base>

   <security:rule-based-permission-resolver security-rules="#{securityRules}"/>
   
   <security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" remember-me="true"/>

   <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">
      <action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}"/>
   </event>
   <event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
      <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
   </event>
   
   <web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="true"
                      max-request-size="100000000" 
                      url-pattern="*.seam" />
   <async:quartz-dispatcher/>
   
</components>
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </dependencies>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="jboss-seam.jar" />
        </resources>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="example.war">
        <dependencies>
          <module name="deployment.example.ear.example.jar" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```